# How can i use SetItemClickListener with Scroll View?

Tags: android, android-intent, scrollview

I need the scroll view and  position so it knows what link to open. The Textviews and list are un-clickable and because of that i can't call the intent. I had them set to false because i read thats what you need to do to the children for it to work. I am completely stuck.
    package com.example.user.siy;

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
  import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;


public class EventsController extends Fragment{

View myView;

private ListView lvProduct;
private EventsListAdapter adapter;
private List<Events> mProductList;
ProgressDialog  mProgressDialog;
String linkHref;

public static  String link;

public ArrayList<String> beerList = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> beerList2 = new ArrayList<String>();



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
    new NewThread().execute();
    return myView;
   }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
       }
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
        mProductList.clear();
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.website.com/").get();
            linkHref = new String("");
            link = new String("");
            Elements beer = doc.select("div[class=av-upcoming-events  avia-
            builder-el-22  el_after_av_hr  avia-builder-el-last]");
            Elements theH4 = beer.select("h4");
            Elements links = beer.select("a"); //Sections

            for (int j = 0; j < theH4.size(); j++) {
                beerList.add( theH4.get(j).text());
            }



            for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {
                linkHref = link.attr("href");
                beerList2.add(linkHref);

            }


            for (int f = 0; f < theH4.size(); f++) {
                mProductList.add(new Events(beerList.get(f), 
            beerList2.get(f)));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Add sample data for list
        //We can get data from DB, webservice here
        //Init adapter
        lvProduct = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        adapter = new EventsListAdapter( getActivity(), mProductList);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


       lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new 
          AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
              position, long id) {
                //Do something
                //Ex: display msg with product id get from view.getTag

                link = beerList2.get(position);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Info.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
            }
          });


         }
           }

//public boolean isOnline() {
    //ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    //NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    //if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        //return true;
    //}
    //return false;
     // }

public String getLink(){

    return link;
     }
     }



      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:clickable="true"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/list"
      android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >




<TextView android:id="@+id/title2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="Mooon Light Stuff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />




      </LinearLayout>

      </ScrollView>




Attempt to fix.





          example = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title2);
            example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                link = beerList2.get(1);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Info.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
              }
                });
```

Comment: ScrollView has no items, it has some views, which you add into it. You can set listeners to the views directly.

Comment: like this?

example = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title2);
            example.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    link = beerList2.get(1);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Info.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });


No my app mon't parse at all and crashes. It's null now.

Comment: that's another problem. You definitely doing something really weird.

Comment: I'm a weird person lol. Idk man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working sample of how to implement OnItemClickListener. 
Make sure your class implements View.OnClickListener & AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener as shown in code. BTW **OnItemClickListener**  will work with scrollview or any other layout that you use. This code is working fine with scroll view in my case.

```
package com.smart.projects.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.smartmob.projects.adapters.NavigationDrawerListAdapter;
import com.smartmob.projects.models.Items;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
  *         <p/>
 *         This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to navigation drawer.
 *         We are going to extend all our other activites from this BaseActivity so that every activity will have Navigation Drawer in it.
 *         This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    /**
     * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list.
     */
    protected static int position;
    /**
     * This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
     */
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    /**
     * Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
     * This layout is protected so that child activity can access this
     */
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    /**
     * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
     * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened.
     */

    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    /**
     * List item array for navigation drawer items.
     */
    protected String[] listArray = {"CML Monitor Features","About CML", "View CBC Report", "Add CBC Report", "View CBC Trend"};
    protected ArrayList<Items> _items;
    boolean dataExists = false;
    /**
     * Base layout node of this Activity
     */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    /**
     * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _items = new ArrayList<Items>();
        _items.add(new Items("About CML", "In Menu click on 'About CML' to learn about CML (Chronic Myeloid Leukemia)", R.drawable.item_1));
        _items.add(new Items("View Report", "In Menu click 'View Report' to view CBC Reports stored in the device", R.drawable.item_2));
        _items.add(new Items("Add Record", "In Menu click 'Add Record' to add a new CBC Record", R.drawable.item_5));
        _items.add(new Items("View CBC Trend", "In Menu click 'CBC trend' to view trends of each CBC parameter in CBC Report", R.drawable.item_4));
       // _items.add(new Items("Tabular Report", "View tabular   CBC Report", R.drawable.item_5));
        //Adding header on list view
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header_layout, null);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this, _items));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
                Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onItemClick-Enter");
            }
        });

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.apple_fruit,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */ {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    /*End of OnCreate*/

    /*Start OnClick*/
    /* Comment : Have to implement with the OnClickListner onClick is called when a view has been clicked.*/
    public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.

        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onClick:Enter");
        final Context context = this;
    }
    /*End of onClick*/

    /**
     * @param position Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "openActivity-Enter");
        /**
         * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
         * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
         * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
         * So that we are setting this in child activity.
         */
//      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      setTitle(listArray[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.smartmob.projects.activity.HomeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.smartmob.projects.activity.MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.smartmob.projects.activity.AddActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TrendActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onCreateOptionsMenu-Enter");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-Enter");
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-Enter"+item);
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit:
                Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-getItemId"+item.getItemId());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exit Application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
                return true;
            /*case R.id.action_settings:
                Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-getItemId"+item.getItemId());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;*/

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    //@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onPrepareOptionsMenu-Enter");
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //////// menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onBackPressed-Enter");
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onItemSelected-Enter");

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Turns out i did not need the scroll-able at all for my app.I don't know how but the ability to scroll down is there without me implementing it on the list view. I will still mark yours as solved tho.It might help someone.

Comment: Cheers! I was responding to your requirement. In fact developers note clearly state that scroll view should not be used with listview bcos listview supports vertical scrolling. If you have specific issues do post them and I will try to help https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html